# Apache frontend can't request to express backend

Tags: apache, express, vue.js

I'm hosting my vueJS frontend on an apache server. Without running the apache just by calling "npm run serve" and visiting my page over http (https is enabled on express backend), I can successfully request to the backend.

When starting apache and visiting the page over https (self-signed SSL certificates), I can't send requests.

Firefox error:

```
Cross-source (cross-origin) request blocked: The same source rule prohibits reading the external resource on https://143.93.46.35:60702/user/login. (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

And chrome:

```
xhr.js:160 POST https://143.93.46.35:60702/user/login net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I enabled https on my express backend like:

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('certs/apache-selfsigned.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/apache-selfsigned.crt')
  }, app)
  .listen(nconf.get('port'), function() {
    console.log(`App listening on port lalala! Go to https://localhost:3000/`)
  });
```

Enabled cors in app.js like:

```
const cors = require('cors');
...
// Enable CORS (cross origin resource sharing)
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: true
}));

app.options('*', cors());
```

And the vue service which handles the axios calls is:

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://inf-education-47.umwelt-campus.de:60702`,
  withCredentials: false, // This is the default
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

export default {
  // user Endpoints
  getUser (email) {
    return apiClient.get(`/user/${email}`)
  },
  registerUser (user) {
    return apiClient.post(`/user/register`, user)
  },
  loginUser (user) {
    return apiClient.post(`/user/login`, user)
  },
  ...
```

In apache I edited the vhost conf to enable cors like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/client/pvapp-client/dist
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    ....
```

What can be the reason for the errors when hosting vue with apache over https?

Comment: Where are your CORS settings? This is probably a CORS issue less than a HTTPS issue.

Comment: I already enabled cors in express. Also in the apache vhost settings. @zero298

Comment: It's a CORS error.  You should show your express cors configuration where you allow this origin

Comment: Just for fun, what happens if you replace the cors config with `app.use(cors())`?

Comment: @Dan also tried that - but didn't change the outcome. Any other ideas? Maybe without the apache https it works too..

Comment: The other idea is the fact that the error shows the IP and not the domain you sent the request to

Comment: But how to solve this? The redirect is the domain and also all routes are set to this and not the IP.

Comment: I don't know, SSL errors have a wide variety of causes.  I would press F12, Network tab, and check the differences between headers when it's working vs. non-working.  If that doesn't help, maybe some SSL config error, which Chrome says

Comment: @Dan Hmm, okay. I already did all that and don't know what else to do, that's why I asked here. It's just not getting a response in the network tab. Either to request isn't getting to the backend or the answer ain't coming through..